# Multiple audio files overlap when played

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have a problem with playing soundfiles: I have multiple buttons, each one associated to a sound file. When sound n.1, for instance, is palying, and I push button to start sound n.2, the two sounds overlap. I want each button to stop the audio played by the other button when it is pressed. Here is my .h file and part of my .m file. I have tried with an " if ", but I receive a " use of undeclared identifier " error. Please keep in mind that I am an absolute beginner, thank you in advance.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {}

-(IBAction)playSound1;
-(IBAction)playSound2;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)playSound1{
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"12-Toxicity" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate=self;
    [theAudio play];

}

@end
```

Comment: You'll need to store both of your `AVAudioPlayer`s in properties, and call `[self.audio1 stop]` in `playSound2` and vice versa...

Comment: Thank you Simon, how can I store them...I suppose, in the .h file ? I remember doing something that worked and then I accidentally deleted code...

Answer (score 0):

This code does the job... And, as a bonus, your app only has to load the music files once!

```
// ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (strong) AVAudioPlayer* sound1Player;
@property (strong) AVAudioPlayer* sound2Player;
- (IBAction)playSound1;
- (IBAction)playSound2;

@end

// ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *pathOne = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"12-Toxicity" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (pathOne) {
        self.sound1Player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathOne] error:NULL];
        self.sound1Player.delegate = self;
    }

    NSString *pathTwo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"13-Psycho" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (pathOne) {
        self.sound2Player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathTwo] error:NULL];
        self.sound2Player.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (IBAction)playSound1 {
    if (self.sound2Player.playing)
        [self.sound2Player stop];
    [self.sound1Player play];
}

- (IBAction)playSound2 {
    if (self.sound1Player.playing)
        [self.sound1Player stop];
    [self.sound2Player play];
}

@end
```

Comment: I am speechless...thank you ! Have agood night or whatever time it is in your timezone ;)

Comment: No worries @Nicola, good luck with the rest of your project! :)